# Using GROUP BY to COUNT number of purchases when the quantity of each transaction is stored in a separate field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, phpmyadmin

I have a table called `orders` where each row stores an order or purchase. This is a sample of its data:

[image]

In the table above, each `id` corresponds to an order. `product_id` is the ID of the product that was bought in the transaction. Notice how there is a column called `quantity` that stores how many products were bought on each order. What I need is a query that returns the number of sales by `product_id`. This is what I have done so far to achieve it:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), `product_id` FROM `orders` GROUP BY `deal_id`;
```

This is the result:

[image]

The problem is that the result is ignoring the column `quantity`. I need to write the SQL query in a way that takes into account the `quantity`. Thank you.

Comment: Add `SUM(quantity)`?

Comment: You said "I need a query that returns the number of transactions". What does the quantity have to do with that?

Comment: How should it take the quantity into acount?

Comment: @Barmar Because each row represents a transaction, meaning an order or a purchase. Some purchases have more than one product. Example, you buy two t-shirts, that is a single transaction but the quantity is 2 because you are buying two t-shirts, not one.

Comment: But you said you wanted the number of transactions, not the number of shirts.

Comment: @Barmar I apologize, you are right. I just edited it to say: "What I need is a query that returns the number of sales by product_id".

Comment: Then use `SUM(quantity)` instead of `COUNT(id)`.

Comment: @Barmar It works. Thank you so much. Please write it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: This is too minor to bother answering.

Comment: @Barmar It was the solution to my problem but you do not have to answer it if you do not want to.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos That was the solution. Feel free to write it as an answer so that I can accept it and have this question marked as answered/solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of sales by product would look something like this:

```
SELECT o.product_id, COUNT(*) as num_orders, SUM(o.quantity) as total_quantity
FROM orders o
GROUP BY o.product_id;
```

You are learning SQL, so here is some advice:

- Always qualify your column names, so you -- or anyone else -- knows which columns they come from.
- In an aggregation query, put the unaggregated columns first (unless you have a good reason for doing otherwise).
- In an aggregation query, be sure that the unaggregated columns match the `GROUP BY` columns.  If the unaggregated columns are first, this is simpler.

Comment: Good advice. Thank you. I just wanted clarification about this item: `"In an aggregation query, put the unaggregated columns first (unless you have a good reason for doing otherwise)."` Is that a convention or good practice? How about putting it last and doing it consistently like that so that you always expect to have all aggregated columns first and unaggregated columns last?

Comment: @JaimeMontoya . . . It is easier to see that they match the `group by`.  Admittedly, I've always preferred the result set with the grouping columns first, but the advice here was for matching to the `group by`.

Comment: It makes sense and it sounds like a good practice to put the grouping columns first.

Answer (score 0):

As Giorgos Betsos and Barmar suggested, this was the solution:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity), `product_id` FROM `orders` GROUP BY `product_id`;
```

Comment: @Strawberry I fixed it. You are right. I had written something wrong but it is fixed now and you would agree with this new version because it works for me.